# Audio clip not playing when compiled

Tags: java, audio, methods, resources

in a recent discussion on StackOverflow I was trying to resolve an imageicon issue that didn't display images after compilation, only when ran in eclipse. This problem was solved by changing the location of my resources folder from my project folder to the src folder. I was also taught to get my resources with the following code:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/picture.jpg"));
```

Without looking at how I had coded my audio method, I asked if the method of putting resources inside the src folder was the same for all types of resources, in which I was told, pretty much. Anyway, now I have got to my audio code, I am a little unsure of how to implement the "getClass().getResource()" line into it.

As it stands my audio works as intended, when ran in eclipse, but when compiled it has the same issue as the images used too. I know that the problem is very similar, but I believe it is a matter of coding, or lack of it. Any pointers, or examples will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

SOURCE CODE:

```
public static void menusong(){
try {
    AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("sounds/dre2.wav"));
    bgclip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    bgclip.open(ais);
    bgclip.start();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(33000);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you building a Jar file containing all your code and resources?

Comment: I wasn't, but am trying to get it that way. So far I have all my resources inside my src folder, Im trying to modify my code so it will allow me to jar it all together...if that makes sense to you?

Comment: My code shown above used to work when ran in eclipse and whilst the resources were in the project folder. Now I have moved all my resources into the src folder with my code, but my code needs to be edited somehow to work as it no longer works in eclipse or when compiled.

Comment: Your `new File` uses a file path relative to the current directory - the current directory is probably not the 'src' folder. Look at using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()` to pass an `InputStream`  to `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream`.

Comment: I have actually just been looking at this, but the example says to write the following:   URL url = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(file); and to add it below the first 'try'. But on his example, 'this' is relative to his program. What can I change it too?   ....or am I looking at this wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Right, got it!  Instead of this:

AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("sounds/dre2.wav"));

I changed it to this:

AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(*classname*.class.getClass().getResource("sounds/dre2.wav"));

All is now working beautifully when compiled, thanks anyway for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: Though your answer didn't helped me but gave me hope that it can be solved and I finally figured out to solve it.